# Update scope after a resource delete

Tags: angularjs

I would like to update `$scope` after a call to a resource delete. The resource is defined as

```
meanApp.factory('Group', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/v1/groups/:groupId', {groupId: '@_id'}, {
        update: { method: 'PATCH'}
    });
});
```

The `ui-router` controller:

```
resolve: {
    groups: ['Group', function (Group) {
        return Group.query();
    }
    ]
},
controller: function ($scope, groups) {
    $scope.myData = groups;

    $scope.deleteGroup = function (group) {
        group.$delete(function(data){
            group.$query().then(function(data) {
                $scope.groups = data;
            })
        });
    }
}
```

The delete is working, the `$query` in the delete callback is also called returning the correct result. But then I get an exception and the scope is not refreshed.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://www.example.com:3000/lib/angular-resource.js:487:47
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://www.example.com:3000/lib/angular.js:309:21)
    at $http.then.value.$resolved (http://www.example.com:3000/lib/angular-resource.js:486:37)
```

The angular-resource code issue seems to be that value is undefined

```
if (action.isArray) {
    value.length = 0;
    forEach(data, function (item) {
        value.push(new Resource(item));
    });
```

**EDIT**

If I use the class syntax instead of the instance syntax it works:

```
    $scope.deleteGroup = function (group) {
        group.$delete(function(data){
            Group.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
                $scope.groups = data;
            })
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
    group.$delete(function(data){
        group.$query().$promise.then(function(data) {
            $scope.groups = data;
        })
    });
```

Resource actions exposes the promise in their return value, so you cannot call then() directly on them.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined. In the log, I can see that the `$promise` is undefined. And I still get the other exception.

Comment: From my understanding you use $promise for the class syntax `Group.query().$promise.then` but not for the instance syntax `group.$query().then`. I can be wrong. BTW it's now working with the class syntax but not the instance syntax.